# Performing gradle build in android studio freezes up UI in Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build-process, freeze, android-studio-2.0

Whenever I start my app from Android Studio and a gradle build is being performed the gradle build process freezes up my Windows 10 Environment. UI and sound freezes temporarily. I haven't found a way to change settings somehow so this issue doesn't occur.
I'm running Android Studio 2.0 on a HP Envy i7 16GB.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?